# Searching for items in different tables with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I was wondering how to create a PHP search form to perform a search function in three tables: phones, manufacturer and operatingsystem. The user will search for a price
i.e. typing "350" would search the Price field in the **phones** table and display all items worth 350 and under or searching for "Android" would search the **operatingsystem** table and display all phones that run Android.

However, the **operatingsystem** table has a primary key called OSID but the **phones** table has a foreign key referencing the OSID. How would I get it to pull up results based on a search for Android when the **phones** table contains the ID rather than the name of the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood well...

you have a table: `phone` , it has the ID of the reference from the table `operating_system`, and the same with `manufacturer`, so, for example, i have in operating system's table entries like

operating_system

1. samsung
2. Nokia
3. Iphone

and manufacturer

1. Mac
2. Nokia

so, in my table phones I have something like

id / name  /    operating_system / manufacturer / price

1 / samsung galaxy / android / samsung / 300usd

so, If you want to show all the details for a search for phones under 350 usd u need to do something like this

```
select * from operating_system, manufacturer, phones
where phones.operating_system = operating_system.id
and manufacturer.id = phone.manufacturer
and phone.price < 350
```

and later show the results..

Answer (score 0):

And what about creating a fourth table that indexes the content of all the other tables?

You could set up this table to have a primary key (auto increment), a second field (0, table 1; 1, table 2; 2, table 3) and a third field with a foreign key that references to the element in the specified table. Then a last field will include a single word.

The search query may be splitted into words and queried against this fourth table.

And then SELECT and JOIN the matches looking for them in the 3 original tables...

Then in the front end you could add some css classes to allow the user to fastly filter (jquery) and keep only a certain type of results so you (she, in fact) remove the false-positives while still allowing the user to change her mind.

Good luck,

Answer (score -1):

You could have different form inputs for different data. That way, you'll know what data to plug into which part of the SQL query.

Though, reinventing the wheel is not a typically recommended activity for a developer in 2013. You could use something that already exists, like [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/). There are many alternatives to this, I'm sure, but it's a start...

A couple of advices, though:

- NEVER EVER EVER trust the user. This includes stuff he's typing into a search box. Always escape it, to protect yourself against SQL Injections.
- If you plan on doing client side validation using Javascript, then do it on the server-side too. Anyone can disable their Javascript in their browsers...

Comment: I'm basically trying to find the simplest way to do it.